# Prove that this kind of equation has unique solution

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Assume that $$f\in C(R)$$ and $$g\in C^1(R)$$ prove that
$$y''+f(y)y'+g(y)=0$$ with $$y(a)=b_1$$ $$y'(a)=b_2$$as an initial values has unique solution.
I had tried to use this change of variables $$x_1=y$$ $$x_2=y'$$ then I used Picard theorem but it didn't helpful.!
Thanks!

Comment: The claim is false. Take $f=g=0$. Then $y(x)=b+m(x-a)$ is a solution of $y''=0$ with $y(a)=b$.

Comment: There won't be a unique solution unless you specifiy $y'(a)$ as well.